# Database connection with python displays wrong results when included

Tags: python, debugging

```
global db
    cursor=db.cursor()


    query="""INSERT INTO Properties (Property_Num, Published_Date, Title,Price,Bedroom,Agency_Fee, Bathroom, Size,Prop_ref,Furnished_status,Rent_payment,Building_info,Amenities,Trade_name,Licence, RERA_ID,Phone_info,Short_link) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    cursor.execute(query,(count_curr, date_result, title_result, price_result, bedroom_result, agencyfee_result, bathroom_result, size_result, propertyref_result, furnished_result, rent_is_paid_result, building_result, Amenities_result, tradename_result, licencenum_result, reraid_result, phone_result, link_result))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

The loop structure is like this and the database connection is in the function every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(a['href'])

```
while i<=40: 


    for a in link: #has 25 loops which prints something
        every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(a['href']) 

    i+=1
```

Problem is that everytime I execute the code, it prints the 25 items without even executing the code(i checked it by putting a dummy print statement which is not printed in the first 25 loops). it just simply prints 25 times and then the code execute. No formating and change of the code is executed in the 1st loop. Its like it remembers something in the database and keep executing that every first loop of the while statement. from the second loop it just starts printing well

Here is my whole program (For reference)

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import MySQLdb
import re
import pdb





def getting_urls_of_all_pages(): 
    print "here is the fist loop"
    i=1
    while i<=40: #40 is the total number of main pages
        url_rent_flat='http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/?page='+str(i) #url of the main page (iterating to 40)


        link=[]
        htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url_rent_flat).read()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)

        link=soup.find_all('a',xtclib=re.compile("listing_list_\d+_title_link"),href=True) #stores all the links (25) links of the page

        """
        Part 2: passing each property url to process for data extraction
        """

        for a in link:
            every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(a['href']) 

        i+=1




def every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(url):

    print "here is the second loop"

    global count_prop

    count_curr=""
    date_result=""
    title_result=""
    price_result=""
    bedroom_result="" 
    agencyfee_result="" 
    bathroom_result="" 
    size_result=""
    propertyref_result=""
    furnished_result=""
    rent_is_paid_result=""
    building_result=""
    Amenities_result=""
    tradename_result=""
    licencenum_result=""
    reraid_result=""
    phone_result=""
    link_result=""




    """
    Part1: Extracting data
    """
    try:
        htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)
        print "\nProperty Number: ", count_prop,
        count_curr=str(count_prop)
    except:
        count_curr="Error"



    #date
    try:
        date=soup.find("h3","listing-details-header","span")
        date_result= str(date.get_text().encode("utf-8").strip()[20:])
        print "\nPublished date: ", date_result
    except:
        date_result="Error"


    #title
    try:
        title= soup.find('span',{'id':'listing-title-wrap'})
        title_result= str(title.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8"))
        print "Title: ",title_result
    except:
        title_result="Error"

    #price
    try:
        price = soup.find('span',{'id':'actualprice'})
        price_result= str(price.get_text())
        print "Price: ",price_result
    except:
        price_result="Error"

    #Agency Fee, Bedroom, Bathroom, Size
    spans_ABBS= []
    for a in soup.select(".important-fields li span"):
        spans_ABBS.append(a.text.strip())

    strongs_ABBS=[]
    for a in soup.select(".important-fields li strong"):
        strongs_ABBS.append(a.text.strip())


    for name, value in zip(spans_ABBS, strongs_ABBS):
        if name=="Agency Fees:":
            try:
                agencyfee_result= str(value)
                print "Agency Fees: ", agencyfee_result
            except:
                agencyfee_result="Error"

        elif name=="Bedrooms:":
            try:
                bedroom_result= str(value)
                print "Number of Bedrooms: ",bedroom_result
            except:
                bedroom_result="Error"

        elif name=="Bathrooms:":
            try:
                bathroom_result= str(value)
                print "Number of Bathrooms: ", bathroom_result
            except:
                bathroom_result="Error"

        elif name=="Size:":
            try:
                size_result= str(value)
                print "Size of the property: ",size_result
            except:
                size_result="Error"

    #Property Reference, Furnished, Listed By, Rent Is Paid, Building, Amenities: 
    spans_others=[]
    for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li span"):
            spans_others.append(a.text.strip())

    strongs_others=[]
    for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li strong"):
        strongs_others.append(a.text.strip())



    for name, value in zip(spans_others, strongs_others):
        if name=="Listed by:":
            break

        elif name=="Property Reference:":
            try:
                propertyref_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Property reference in Dubizel: ",propertyref_result
            except:
                propertyref_result="Error"

        elif name=="Furnished:":
            try:
                furnished_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Furnished status: ",furnished_result
            except:
                furnished_result="Error"


        elif name=="Rent Is Paid:":
            try:
                rent_is_paid_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Rent payment: ",rent_is_paid_result
            except:
                rent_is_paid_result="Error"

        elif name=="Building:":
            try:
                building_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Building info: ",building_result
            except:
                building_result="Error"
        elif name=="Amenities:":
            try:
                for a in value.split(","):
                    Amenities_result+=a.strip()+","
                print Amenities_result
            except:
                Amenities_result="Error"



    #Agents info --> TTrade Name, DED Licence Number, RERA Registration Number
    spans_broker=[]
    for a in soup.select("#broker-details li span"):
            spans_broker.append(a.text.strip())

    strongs_broker=[]
    for a in soup.select("#broker-details  li strong"):
        strongs_broker.append(a.text.strip())


    for name, value in zip(spans_broker, strongs_broker):
        if name=="Trade Name:":
            try:
                tradename_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Trade name: ",tradename_result
            except:
                tradename_result="Error"

        elif name=="DED Licence Number:":
            try:
                licencenum_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Licence #: ",licencenum_result
            except:
                licencenum_result="Error"

        elif name=="RERA Registration Number:":
            try:
                reraid_result=str(value.strip())
                print "RERA ID #: ",reraid_result
            except:
                reraid_result="Error"


    # phone num
    try:
        phone=soup.find("div", "phone-content")
        for a in phone:
            phone_result= str(a).get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")
        print "Phone information:", phone_result
    except:
        phone_result="Error"


    #link
    try:
        link = soup.find('input',{'id':'short-link-input'})
        link_result= str(link.get('value'))
        print "Short Reference link: ", link_result
    except:
        link_result="Error"


    # #double check of the types before conversion
    # print map(type, (count_curr, date_result, title_result, price_result, bedroom_result, agencyfee_result, bathroom_result, size_result, propertyref_result, furnished_result, rent_is_paid_result, building_result, Amenities_result, tradename_result,licencenum_result,reraid_result,phone_result,link_result))




    count_prop+=1

    # """
    # Connecting to Database and putting data into in
    # """




    db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","ahmed","Properties")
    cursor=db.cursor()
    query="""INSERT INTO Properties (Property_Num, Published_Date, Title,Price,Bedroom,Agency_Fee, Bathroom, Size,Prop_ref,Furnished_status,Rent_payment,Building_info,Amenities,Trade_name,Licence, RERA_ID,Phone_info,Short_link) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    cursor.execute(query,(count_curr, date_result, title_result, price_result, bedroom_result, agencyfee_result, bathroom_result, size_result, propertyref_result, furnished_result, rent_is_paid_result, building_result, Amenities_result, tradename_result, licencenum_result, reraid_result, phone_result, link_result))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()



#-----------------------------------------------------------




count_prop=1
getting_urls_of_all_pages()
```

Comment: Am I not closing the connection or what?

Comment: Could you post the function every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction()? And also what is "link"?

Comment: I posted the whole program for your reference

Comment: I am stuck since one day on this. please find the bug. I dont know why the first 25 loops doesnt enter the program. you see the print statement in the start of the getting_urls_of_all_pages():  function. it doesnt get executed in the first 25 loops. from 26th its executed

Comment: there is an error in the program. it doesnt even give that error. it gives that error after executing 25 loops. whats going on?????

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The about the db variable which i didnt use correctly. it gives that error after 25 loops. actually it gives every kind of error after 25 loops regardless of what it is